# htaccess rule fails sometimes but not always

Tags: .htaccess

i have the following rule to my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/(.*).html/?$ article.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

When a user goes to

```
www.mydomain.com/en/this-is-an-article.html
```

the rule forward to article.php and show the page.

The problem is that sometimes the rules fails and instead of go to

```
www.mydomain.com/en/this-is-an-article.html
```

its go to

```
www.mydomain.com/article.php
```

and the page is not render because the passing parameters are not send and can not handle it

If you make another click to see the page the page render as expected.

Its the first time i see something like that.

full htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

Options -Indexes   
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>

# WEEK
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf|swf|js|css|jpg|png|gif|JPG)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>


<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|ttf|woff)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>


#fcp.php
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/fcp.php?$ fcp.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

#tuner.php
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/index-b/(.*).html/?$ index-b.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/catalog-b/(.*).html/?$ catalog-b.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#product.php
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/product/(.*).html/?$ product.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#article.php
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/(.*).html/?$ article.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#controller.php
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/(.*)/p/([^.]+)?$ controller.php?lang=$1&url=$2&p=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(el|en)/(.*)/?$ controller.php?lang=$1&url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

#index.php
RewriteRule ^(el|en)?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Can anyone help

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules also?

Comment: no but its the only one that has the .html so for sure its not confused  with any other rule.

Comment: ok can you paste your complete .htaccess in question?

Comment: you can see the complete .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try placing this code at top of your .htaccess:

```
# disable MultiViews as it conflicts with mod_rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# skip further rewrites if rewrite has already happened OR else
# if request is for a valid file/directory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: added some comments for explanation.

Comment: thanks i will give it a try but i will need sometime to be sure that everything works fine, after all the fails is not always happen and i have to trap it